# Does each terminal at JFK have its own screening and how many per terminal?

Tags: airports, airport-security

As I understand it: there were[8 terminals at JFK of which two are demolished](http://www.airport-jfk.com/terminals.php).  To move from the 'sterile' area of one terminal to any other terminal, passengers must

1. exit the sterile area,
2. [take the air train or a shuttle bus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46908/at-jfk-can-you-move-between-terminals-airside-on-domestic-flights),
3. and be rescreened by the security.

This would imply that each terminal has at least one (or more) TSA screening entry nodes per terminal.  **Is there a good resource that enumerates the number of screening entry nodes for terminals 2,4,5,&8?   Bonus for any other Terminals.**

[JFK Terminal map of Terminal 5](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airport-map.html) does not explicitly call out the screening point. UPDATE: the legend in other terminal maps provide the symbol for security.

[image]

I would like to understand the answer to the question so as to get a sense of what it would take to transit from one sterile area of the terminal to the other.  The more entry nodes could confer greater speed.  If you have experience transiting through these terminal entry nodes, please state this in the response

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: How is this a travel question?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by a screening "node".  Anyway, this isn't of much use in estimating screening speed unless you also know something about how many people are being screened.

Comment: You might also want to clarify the title.  The answer to the title question is simply "yes', but your question is asking for something much more detailed.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airport-map.html?  There are maps for each terminal showing the security checkpoints.  I am not sure, but that might answer your question.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you: excellent observation.  Promote your suggestion to an answer and you shall receive credit.

Comment: If you want estimates of how long it will take to go through security, rather than the number of "nodes," then [the TSA website has them](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/wait_times_home.aspx), though they may be of limited utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maps at http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airport-map.html where you can see the locations of security checkpoints as a dotted red region.  There is one checkpoint shown in each terminal.  I do not know what you mean by "entry node" but perhaps this is what you were looking for.

If your question is about the specific configuration of the checkpoints (number of waiting lines / ID check podiums / X-ray scanners / metal detectors / etc) then note that such things are easily and frequently reconfigured, so any answer could be instantly obsolete.